# How to adjust line spacing in Textmate 2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

How to adjust the height of line spacing in Textmate 2?

[image]

i.e. preferably like Textmate 1 (on the right).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fontLeadingDelta -float 0
 defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fontAscentDelta -float 0
```

source: textmate on [github](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues/373)

Comment: Nowadays, see the Wiki for reference: https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings